# Class handler.GameSessionLambda has no public zero-argument constructor: java.lang.Exception

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, dagger-2, dagger

I'm working with Lambda in Java and added Dagger2. However I'm having problem injecting objects to my lambda handler.

I'm getting the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v86wn.png)

`Class handler.GameSessionLambda has no public zero-argument constructor: java.lang.Exception java.lang.Exception: Class handler.GameSessionLambda has no public zero-argument constructor Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: handler.GameSessionLambda.\<init\>() at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)`

InjectedConstants:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kggn.png)
Module Class:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V63Pb.png)
Component interface:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwnPp.png)
The Handler:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tdmv8.png)

Its working without dagger2, but since I want my handler to hold more logic and services I wanted to add dependency injection to follow best practices and save little runtime.By the way if I included an empty constructor then the lambda ignores the other constructor which results in null for the injected objects.

Comment: "I want my handler to hold more logic" - what does that mean?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I will be adding more services, thats why I want to use dependency injection such as dagger

Comment: Don't post images of code! Put it in your post instead.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The implementation of dagger is correct however Lambda requires a zero-argument constructor. So my workaround was to inject the objects directly instead of constructor injection.

[Java Doc](http://ask-sdk-java-javadocs.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/com/amazon/ask/SkillStreamHandler.html#:%7E:text=Lambda%20functions%20written%20in%20Java,argument%20constructor%20and%20implement%20RequestStreamHandler%20.)